# Twitter bootstrap. Закрытие модального окна.

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом на [этой странице](http://bootstrap2modaldemo.scripting.com/) можно отключить возможность закрытия модального окна при клике вне области модального окна? Мне важно знать, какая настройка отвечает за включение/выключение этой возможности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там в плагине есть такие параметры:

```
  $.fn.modal.defaults = {
      backdrop: true
    , keyboard: true
    , show: true
  }
```

Соответственно `backdrop` отвечает за фон.

Скорее всего параметры читаются из ссылки:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#windowTitleDialog">Set Window Title</a>
```

Вам нужно добавить

```
data-backdrop="false"
```

Больше инфы: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

Если добавить data-backdrop="false", то вместе исчезнет и сам фон, а окно перестанет быть по настоящему модальным. Правильнее будет:  data-backdrop="static"